# PL/SQl nested If loops inner if loop not exiting

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-if

Hi everyone I am a bit new to PL/SQL so am a bit confused. I have a Cursor called `rec` and while looping through it I have two nested IF statements.

```
CURSOR Cur IS
    SELECT Mil.Id,
           Mil.Record_Num,
           Mil.Status,
           Mil.file_processed,
           Mil.Updated_By
      FROM status_log mil
     WHERE Mil.file_processed != 'Processed'
     For Update of Mil.file_processed;

 FOR Rec IN Cur LOOP

                IF (Rec.status = 'Ready' OR Rec.status = 'Go') THEN
                     IF Length(Rec.Zip) = 5 AND
               (Substr(Rec.Zip, 1, 3) = '303' OR
                Substr(Rec.Zip, 1, 3) = '304' ) THEN 

                        l_state:= 'ATL';                               
                    END IF;

          UPDATE status_log mil
             SET file_processed = 'Processed'
           WHERE current of cur        

        END IF;

COMMIT;
          END LOOP;
```

Now whenever the cursor has one record that satisfies the second `IF`(i.e Zip is 5 in length and the code starts with 303 or 304) it doesnt hit the `update` statement anymore for  that records and all record after that. I even tried using the `EXIT` statement after the logic in the `IF` loop but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post the cursor, and "the code to do something" :)

Comment: Is there any chance that you are throwing an error and exiting silently? (i.e. your procedure has `exception when others then null;`)

Comment: Hi the code to do something i just a setting a variable to a particular value. That code is not responsible since I commented that out and tried running it with a blank block and yet the same problem. Edited the code a bit check update.

Comment: @Allan I am not throwing and exiting silently. The Only thing in the `exception when others` block is a notification that the block has been hit but the exception is not being hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IFs aren't loops.  This may actually be an important point since you say you've tried using an `EXIT`, and the purpose of that statement is to exit from the immediately enclosing loop.  In this case, that means the loop over the cursor (unless possibly your "code to do something" includes other loops).  So any `EXIT` you put in there would have caused the entire loop to terminate.

If it doesn't execute the update, then the "code to do something" is either (a) using an explicit command that affects the flow control, such as `EXIT`, `CONTINUE`, or `GOTO`, or (b) encountering an error that is causing control to switch to some exception handler somewhere.

If the execute is updating but failing, then you should be seeing an error -- unless, again, there is an exception handler somewhere that is hiding it from you.

Comment: The do something was just setting a value to a variable. I tried using a blank loop by commenting that part out but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

1. it is possible that status_log rows to update are locked by another session.
   You can query the blocking_session column of v$session view.
2. the "code to do something" is doing something.
3. You update the column `file_processed` but lock the row for the column `status`. I've not tested, but that could be an issue.

Comment: Actually sorry that was my typo I was locking file_processed not status. Edited the post. I think I am just hitting an exception somewhere and the package that we use to log errors isnt working. SO am writing some dbms output lines to see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your `CURSOR` definition includes or excludes the table `status_log`... That could be the problem.

Comment: Should not be the cause - Oracle guarantees that the cursor "sees" a consistent set of data once it's opened.